# What is a HTML5 "metadata element"?

Tags: html

Good afternoon all,

I've just realised that this piece of code [validates](http://validator.w3.org/) as 100% valid HTML5:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <title>asd</title>
  <script src="Js.js"></script>
  <script>alert('1');</script>
</html>
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) states that the permitted parent elements of the `<script>` tag is:

> Any element that accepts metadata elements, or any element that accepts phrasing content. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/script))

I was wondering does anyone know what does a metadata element mean? What does *phrasing content* mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Elements belonging to the metadata content category modify the presentation or the behavior of the rest of the document, set up links to others documents, or convey other out of band information.
>
> Elements belonging to this category are `<base>`, `<command>`, `<link>`, `<meta>`, `<noscript>`, `<script>`, `<style>` and `<title>`.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_categories#Metadata_content

The reason why your document validates even without `<head>` and `<body>` is that they became optional in HTML5. Actually, even `<html>` is optional so the following code is valid HTML5, too:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>asd</title>
<script src="Js.js"></script>
<script>alert('1');</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help =) Btw since I omitted the `<head>` and `<body>` tags, Do you mean to say that browsers will guess (react differently) whether my `<script>` tags should belong to `<head>` / `<body>`, or is there already a pre-set standard by HTML5 which guides how browsers should react upon omitted tags?

Comment: My guess would be that they behave like in `<body>` - but I'm not sure. I guess you can find it somewhere in the HTML5 specs.

Comment: @Pacerier - The HTML5 spec does indeed describe what happens. In your example, the script elements will be inside the head element. The rules are pretty bizarre really - you can find them here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tree-construction.htm - but in practice it makes very little difference whether script elements are put into the head or body elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link defining what they mean by metadata elements and phrasing elements. Hope that clears up which is which. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.metadata